# Does "hasaccepted" imply "is:question"?

Tags: support, search

This might be something that only Stack Exchange personnel can answer, but...

When using advanced search terms, if I were looking for all of my questions that have an accepted answer

```
user:me is:question hasaccepted:yes
```

would appear to give the exact same results as

```
user:me hasaccepted:yes
```

since, of course, only questions can have an accepted answer.

From a *results* standpoint, the `is:question` is redundant. But what about on the query back-end? Does `hasaccepted:*` already include the same query filter as `is:question`? Or **does adding `is:question` make for a more efficient query** by eliminating more records right away? Or does it make no never mind?

In a related vein, is there any reason why `hasaccepted:yes` would ever give different results than `is:question hasaccepted:yes`?

Comment: I believe so, in the same way that `isaccepted:yes` implies being an answer.

Comment: I've always assumed this to be the case (that `is:question` is implied by the `hasaccepted`) but it would be interesting to understand if there is any benefit to adding is:question to the query.

Comment: As a footnote: trying `hasaccepted:yes is:answer` results in `in` parameter being overridden: the query returns questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `hasaccepted` does imply `is:question`.

We check for it and patch on an `is:question` - so:

```
user:me hasaccepted:yes
```

Ends up being equivalent to:

```
user:me is:question hasaccepted:yes
```

---

This is true to other search operators that imply a question (such as the number of answers range selector - `answers:`), and of course `isaccepted` implies `is:answer`.

Comment: so, there's no combination of operators that means "return all answers that I wrote on questions without an accepted answer"?